# command not working as expected if run via /bin/sh -c

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to concatenate a set of files. Directory structure is like this:

```
root/features/xxx/multiple_files... -> root/xxx/single_file
```

what i have written (and it works fine):

`for dirname in $(ls -d root/features/*|awk -F/ '{print $NF}');do;mkdir root/${dirname};cat root/features/${dirname}/* > root/${dirname}/final.txt;done`

But when i run the same thing via sh shell

`/bin/sh -c "for dirname in $(ls -d root/features/*|awk -F/ '{print $NF}');do;mkdir root/${dirname};cat root/features/${dirname}/* > root/${dirname}/final.txt;done"`

it gives me errors:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `201201000'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `201201000'
```

My process always appends /bin/sh -c before running any commands. Any suggestions what might be going wrong here? Any alternate ways? I have spent a really long time on this ,without making much headway!

EDIT:
`` `ls -d root/features/*|awk -F/ '{print $NF}' `` returns

```
201201
201201000
201201001
201201002
201201003
201201004
201201005
201201006
201201007
201202000
201205000
201206000
201207000
201207001
201207002
```

Comment: Between double quotes, bash variables will be expanded. To not expand variables. You have to escape each `$` sign with a backslash `\ ` ... (and run `bash` instead of `sh`), Like `/bin/bash -c "for dirname in \$(ls...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to run in the little test environment I set up on my box.  Turns out it didn't like the double quotes.  The issue I ran into was the quotes around the awk statement...if you wrap it in double quotes it prints the whole thing.....I used cut to get the desired result, but my guess is you'll have to change the -f arg to 3 instead of 2..I think.

```
/bin/sh  -c 'for dirname in $(ls -d sh_test/* | awk -F/ '\''{print $NF}'\''); do mkdir sh_test_root/${dirname}; cat sh_test/${dirname}/* > sh_test_root/${dirname}/final.txt;done'
```

edit: Tested edit proposed by nadu and it works fine.  The above reflects that change.

Comment: also, check that the sh that you have tested with from command line is the same as /bin/sh.  is 201201 the name of a file?  Also, odd that its 201 repeated....is something getting appended wrong?...is there a 201?

Comment: By default I am running /bin/bash where the command ran fine. Also trying after removing the extra ";" didnt work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ah, ok I see the issue with /bin/sh -c.  Sorry, looking into it now and will edit answer accordingly

Comment: whats your shebang line at the top of your file?  try adding #!/bin/bash at the top of your script if it's not there

Comment: So I am not writing a script. It is just that I am invoking the command as /bin/sh -c <command_string>. I also edited the question a little bit. Please take a look.

Comment: ah ok, I assume you are constrained to running via /bin/sh for some reason?  I'm checking it out now

Comment: edited the answer, see if you can get that general idea to work for you

Comment: Thanks. This worked! Instead of using cut we can escape the single quotes of awk like nadu suggested.

Comment: y'know that was my first thought but for some reason that didn't work when I tried it, and looking at nadus code I can see why, I only did \'{print $NF}\' rather than '\'' which in hindsight makes more sense!  glad I could help, I don't get to mess around terribly much with shell scripting anymore so it was a fun refresher for me.

Answer (score 5):

Always use `sh -c 'cmd1 | cmd2'` with single quotes.

Always use `sh -eu -xv -c 'cmd1 | cmd2'` to debug.

Always use `bash -c 'cmd1 | cmd2'` if your code is Bash-specific (cf. process substitution, ...).

Remove `;` after `do` in `for ... ; do; mkdir ...`.

Escape possible single quotes within single quotes like so:  `'  -->  '\''`.

(And sometimes just formatting your code clarifies a lot.)

Applied to your command this should look somewhat like this ...

```
# test version
/bin/sh -c '
   for dirname in $(ls -d /* | awk -F/ '\''{print $NF}'\''); do
     printf "%s\n" "mkdir root/${dirname}";
     printf "%s\n" "cat root/features/${dirname}/* > root/${dirname}/final.txt"; 
     echo
   done
' | nl

# test version using 'printf' instead of 'ls'
sh -c '
   printf "%s\000" /*/ | while IFS="" read -r -d "" file; do
     dirname="$(basename "$file")"
     printf "%s\n" "mkdir root/${dirname}";
     printf "%s\n" "cat root/features/${dirname}/* > root/${dirname}/final.txt"; 
     echo
   done
' | nl
```

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the `set -e` suggestion -- that has a lot of unexpected pitfalls (doubly so when combined with `set -u`; perfectly good idioms such as `if [[ $some_var ]]` become unusable). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 for some fun examples.